# No login sound in Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, login, pulseaudio, shutdown

Hi I am new to Kubuntu 16.10 and I have no startup or shutdown sound. I have looked everywhere in system settings and see no setting for either a startup  login or shutdown sound. Can someone tell me where to go to get this? Preferably step by step Konsole commands that I can use to get both sounds working? Thank you in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

**KDE Notifications**

KDE System Settings > Notifications

Event source: Plasma Workspace

Enable the 'Play a sound' at the Login/Logout

[image]

Launch the 'Event Notifications and Actions' from terminal:

```
kcmshell5 kcmnotify
```

Comment: Unfortunately my Kubuntu installation crashed before I saw your answer and I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 LTS But I'm positive that had I not crashed my system this would've worked for me. So thank you so much for taking the time to let me know the solution to this